# You have a nil object when you didn't expect it! You might have expected an instance of Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb

I am writing as below

```
def search

   cuisine=Settings.allcuisines

 begin 
 @orgs = getSearch(params[:lat], params[:lon],params[:zip], params[:dist],   cuisine,params[:num_results])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html {render action: "index"}
    format.json { render json: @orgs }
  end
    messg="success"
    code="0"
    results={:message=>messg,:code=>code}
    resul=Results.new(results)
     resul.save
  rescue Exception => exc
   messg=exc.message
   code="1"
   results={:message=>messg,:code=>code}
   resul=Results.new(results)
     resul.save
   respond_to do |format|
    format.html {render action: "index"}
    format.json { render json: @orgs }
   end

end
```

I am getting error:

> You have a nil object when you didn't expect it! You might have
>   expected an instance of Array. The error occurred while evaluating
>   nil.each

Why is this happening?

Comment: The actual error isn't in that code. It's either in a method that it calls or in your view.

Comment: def getSearch(lat, lon,zip, dist, cuisine, num_results, unit=:mi)
  num_results ||= 10
  unit ||= :mi
  if zip.strip.empty?
    Org.where('content.attribs.name'=>'cuisine', 'content.attribs.value'=>cuisine )
    .geo_near([lon,lat], :max_distance => dist, :spherical => true, num: num_results)
  end
  if(lat.strip.empty? || lon.strip.empty?)
  Zipcode.where('zipcode'=>zip)
 method as above and view is <% for org in @orgs %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= org.name %></td>
    <td><%= org.address.city %></td>
    <td><%= org.address.country %></td>

Comment: You can click "edit" below your question to add in extra information `:)`.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably calling @orgs.each in your view and @orgs is nil. You can try just nesting your iterator in an:

```
- unless @orgs.nil?
  - @orgs.each do |o|
    blah
```

Comment: yes I am using like this in view , <% for org in @orgs %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= org.name %></td>
    <td><%= org.address.city %></td>
    <td><%= org.address.country %></td>